# Optimize a path found by wall follower

Tags: c, algorithm, maze

In a current project, we have a robot which follows a maze. It does this until it finds a black area. After that the robot should go back to the start.

This works for us. But now we want to optimize the way the robot has to go to get to the beginning.

Is there a algorithm which simplifies this kind of a path? We save all the turns in an array which looks like this: `turn_left, turn_right, turn_straight`

Currently we only cut out obvious detours like `turn_left, turn_180, turn_right` to a `turn_straight`.

Is there a way to even further optimize the maze?

Comment: I suppose the distance between two turns is constant (i.e. the maze has square cells). The first thing that comes to mind is to compute the list of absolute positions of the robot from the list of its turns, and search for duplicates. Then you can prune the detour that is between the duplicates.

Comment: No the lines are not all the same length.

Comment: What does `turn_straight` mean? Turn around or don't turn at all (go straigth)?

Comment: Just to be clear, your maze only has 90° turns and branches, but the corridors can be any length ? Does it contain loops ?

Comment: the name is just to indicate that it is beloning to an enum. So it just goes straigth over an intersection.

Comment: There are no loops and it only contains 90 degree turns. The coridors can be any length.

Comment: At the moment it's unclear what the problem is. Please clarify the question. Give a clear problem case (with a picture or ascii art preferably).

Comment: Any time the robot visits the same square twice you can skip all the moves inbetween.

Comment: Since the maze is a tree (i.e. has no loops), the only way the robot can walk the same path twice is after a 180° turn. When you find a 180° turn, you can start traversing the previous turns backwards as long as they are cancelled by the next turns. All of these are redundant, and can be pruned. Doing this until you have no more 180° turn will leave you with the shortest path.